# No system tray icons showing at all!

Tags: release-freya, applications

I am using Elementary OS Freya. All my system tray icons like chrome, hangouts,Geary etc. which used to show on Ubuntu 14.04 are not showing on elementary OS. Is there any way i can get these system tray icons on elementary OS too? I would be happy to provide any extra info about my system if needed.

PS: The default icons for sound, network, and power are there. All the external application icons are not showing.

Comment: If you open geary once, it will be on tray

Comment: I too am looking for a tray, since Slack claims that it is minimizing to it but I can't see it even though I do recieve all notifications correctly :(

Answer (score 0):

There is no "system tray" in elementary OS. There is an indicator API, but these apps are probably using an old, deprecated API that is no longer supported.

Comment: so its not possible to get apps to show on the indicator any more? How about atleast chromium? Any workarounds possible?

Comment: It's possible someone may have written an indicator that emulates the old API, but I don't know anything about it if it exists